# Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using tnsnames.ora

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

`tnsnames.ora` file contains the `Databases` and the their description (`host` + `port`).

- Is it possible to establish a connection relying on the file mentioned above? (Say by providing only the DB name):
- In order to find this file, I have to know the default oracle home I need to check in the windows registry for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Oracle` and then to have all the `KEY_XXX` files and then check which one appears first on the `%PATH%`. Is there a way to automatically find this file on the client computer?

Comment: If you could get your clients to always set the TNS_ADMIN environment variable, it would make finding the file a lot easier.

Comment: @Chris can you please explain it more?

Comment: The Oracle client checks first if TNS_ADMIN is set. It must contain the full path of the directory that contains sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora. Only if it's not set, it searches via the registry.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wasn't even aware that using tnsnames with the thin driver is possible, but apparently it was added somewhere in version 10:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm#BEIDIJCE

In particular:

> Note:
>
> When using TNSNames with the JDBC Thin driver, you must set the oracle.net.tns_admin property to the directory that contains your tnsnames.ora file.
>
> `java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=%ORACLE_HOME%\network\admin`

As mentioned, I haven't checked if this *actually* works.

I don't think that the "find the actual network config directory" logic is available via some Oracle function. You'll have to do it manually as outlined in your question, or maybe rely on the TNS_ADMIN environment variable being present. In that case, the java invocation would be

```
java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=%TNS_ADMIN%
```

Comment: Under windows, replace `$ORACLE_HOME` with `%ORACLE_HOME%` (or the actual path)

Comment: Note: Thin JDBC drivers do not support `include` directive in tnsnames.ora files.

Comment: This works for me in IntelliJ IDEA, however you must add the setting as a VM argument, not as a user defined option in the list box.

Comment: Also... in case the TNS_ADMIN folder has spaces/delimiters, put quotes around it, e.g., 


`java -Doracle.net.tns_admin="%TNS_ADMIN%"`

Answer (score 16):

Well, in some GUIs the TNS driver configuration is simply not implemented or not working (NetBeans for example :-) )

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231526

There is simple workaround here. You can take the entry directly from the tnsnames.ora file and attach it to the jdbc driver string as following:

Example from using odbc7.jar (Oracle 12c JDBC driver for JDK 7) to
connect to Oracle 11gR2 RAC cluster:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=
>   TCP)(HOST=hostA)(PORT=
>   1522))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostB)(PORT=1521)))(SOURCE_ROUTE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DatabaseService)))

Be aware of putting double :: characters in the end as host:port:service, if you will put :: in the end like this:

> jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=
>   TCP)(HOST=hostA)(PORT=
>   1522))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostB)(PORT=1521)))(SOURCE_ROUTE=yes)(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DatabaseService)))::

You will end up with "NL Exception was generated" exception.

Another approach is to configure following property:
    System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin","C:/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/NETWORK/ADMIN");

Of course, instead of hardcoded value, you can for example set up environment variable in your operating system like ORACLE_TNS_ADMIN and then reference it:

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin",System.getenv("ORACLE_TNS_ADMIN"));
```

or pass it to java process via -D switch 
on linux:

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=$ORACLE_TNS_ADMIN
```

and windows:as

```
-Doracle.net.tns_admin=%ORACLE_TNS_ADMIN%
```

Once our application is aware of TNS config file, we can connect by reference service name in TNSNAMES.ora file as in this full example:

```
 // tell the driver where to look for the TNSNAMES.ORA file
System.setProperty(
          "oracle.net.tns_admin",
          "C:/app/product/11.2.0/client_1/NETWORK/ADMIN");

// ORCL is net service name from the TNSNAMES.ORA file
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ORCL";

// load the driver
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;

try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,
                                     "your_username",
                                     "your_password");

  stmt = conn.createStatement();

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT dummy FROM dual");
```

Answer (score 11):

Starting from 18.3, TNS_ADMIN that provides the location of the tnsnames.ora file can be passed as part of the connection URL. Please note the syntax.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@jdbctest_medium?TNS_ADMIN=/test/cloud/network
```

Comment: details are here:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/connect-jdbc-thin-wallet.html#GUID-1640CC02-BF3E-48C2-8FFE-A596614A6A40

Answer (score 4):

Firstly make sure that SQL Developer software is properly installed in your machine. If you are using thin driver, ensure that your ojdbcX.jar file is in your build path. The steps to connect to Oracle data source using TNS Alias name are:

- Set System Property for `oracle.net.tns_admin`. This should point to the directory which has your `tnsnames.ORA` file

  `System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", DIRECTORY_PATH_TO_TNSNAME.ORA_FILE);`
- Register an Oracle driver

  DriverManager.registerDriver(new OracleDriver());
- Create a connection object

  `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@TNS_ALIAS_NAME");`

This should establish the Database connection.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the following

Try this, after some hours of troubleshooting came across a sample which I modified and it works like a gem.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=19.16.200.12)) (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=19.16.200.10)))(load_balance = yes)(connect_data=(SERVICE_NAME=stackdb)))
```

A none load balance sample is given Below:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)
(port=1521)(host=prodHost)))(connect_data=(INSTANCE_NAME=ORCL)))
```

Here is the URL that helped https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/jdbcthin.htm#JJDBC28202

Comment: This looks like a duplicate answer, you've answered a few minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718340/jdbc-oracle-thin-client-to-fail-over-to-second-db/58311573#58311573

Comment: This answer is not using tnsnames.ora at all, which was a criteria of the original question