# JDBC Oracle Thin Client to Fail Over to Second DB

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I've read that I can set up a JDBC thin client connection string so that my Java program will attempt to connect to the first database first then, if there's a problem, it will attempt to connect to the second database.

However this isn't happening in practice.

If I use the following string:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS_LIST = 
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = site1)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
    (ADDRESS = 
      (PROTOCOL = TCP)
      (HOST = site2)
      (PORT = 1521)
    )
  )
  (FAILOVER=ON)
  (FAILOVER_MODE=
    (TYPE=SELECT)
    (METHOD=BASIC)
    (RETRIES=20)
    (DELAY=3)
  )
  (LOAD_BALANCE = OFF)
  (CONNECT_DATA =
    (SERVER = DEDICATED)
    (SERVICE_NAME = MYDB)
  )
)
```

Now I know that `site1` is down and `site2` is up. If I specify `site2` *first* in my list then I get a connection (just like I'd expect if I just tried to connect to `site2`). However when I put `site1` first I get the same error as if I tried to connect directly to `site1` - which is:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
  java.lang.RuntimeException:
    java.sql.SQLException:
      ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

Does the Oracle thin client require the first database to be working on connect and only failover if something goes wrong during the connection? What I want is for the application to try the next server if the connection to the first server fails (which I could do using `try { ... } catch { ... }` application logic but would prefer the driver to take care of the details for me).

Answer (score 2):

Your using the same service_name as your SID.
Even if you stop the service MYDB, it'll always find it because of the SID.
primary db is in mount mode, so that explains the error you get.

Create a new service_name (other than your SID) and connect on that servicename

For instance: service_name = MYDB_CLIENT

Answer (score 0):

Try this, after some hours of trouble shooting came across a sample which I modified and it works like a gem.

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=19.16.200.11)) (address=(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)(host=19.16.200.10)))(load_balance = yes)(connect_data=(SERVICE_NAME=stackdb)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Connection Management Strategies](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc-ucp-conn-mgmt-strategies-3045654.pdf) for the recommended connection URL. See an example below.

[image]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)