# Verifying tnsnames.ora syntax in Windows

Tags: java, oracle, windows-7, tnsnames

I have a tnsnames.ora file that was working (using Java to connect to a database).  Someone gave me several more names and descriptions to add.  I added these at the bottom and changed what I was trying to connect to to one of the new names.  I received this error from testing (actual name changed for privacy):

> java.lang.AssertionError: Error running RandProv query: IO Error: could not resolve the connect identifier "HOST.COMPANY.COM"

I have this entry in my tnsnames.ora file.  Unfortunately I am not sure I can publish it here.  Maybe I can if again I change the names.  It is below.  Anyway I am wondering whether there is an online tool to check the syntax?  Back when I was using Linux I could have used one of the bash scripts I found.  Unfortunately now, I am using windows 7.  Does anyone know a way to verify syntax?

Here is the entry (and remember, connections which were in the file before worked, and the error is not that the connection is bad but rather that it cannot resolve it):

```
HOST.COMPANY.COM=
(DESCRIPTION = 
 (ADDRESS = 
  (PROTOCOL = TCP)
  (HOST = servername.COMPANY.COM)
  (PORT = 1784)
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA = 
  (FAILOVER_MODE = 
    (TYPE = select)
    (METHOD = basic)
    (RETRIES = 20)
    (DELAY = 1)
  )
  (SERVER = dedicated)
  (SERVICE_NAME = NAME2.COMPANY.COM)
  )
)
```

Any ideas how to check the syntax?  I know it might be caused farther up.

Comment: By the way, I am running this in Eclipse with Maven and Java and testng

Comment: First try to run tnsping host.company.com from terminal and post the output here, that way we'll know if the problem is with oracle or java.

Comment: Are you sure you changed the same file Java is using? I seem to recall it doesn't necessarily use the main ORACLE_HOME one, or the one pointed to by TNS_ADMIN (or LOCAL).

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195154/266304) suggests you might be supplying the file location as a command-line flag to Java; can you confirm that is the file you changed?

Comment: Not sure what happened to my response.  This is being run from Eclipse.  At the top of the project file is tsanames.ora and in configuration.properties is the data base connection name to use.  Not sure how to do tsping.  It won't work from command window.  And I am only executing, I did not write the code.  I can try to contact author to see if he has any suggestions.  Not sure I can contact him though.

Comment: Just type this line in command window - 
tnsping host.company.com, and tell us what output is received.

Comment: Hi.  I found the problem.  The start of your name you can't have any spaces.  There was one space before the HOST.COMPANY.COM.  It looks like when I pasted above it removed the space.  It seems like oracle should know enough to trim off leading spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same here - you need to insert a blank at the beginning of line2:

```
HOST.COMPANY.COM=
 (DESCRIPTION =
```