# Using settings from TNSNAMES.ORA in HikariCP

Tags: java, hikaricp, tnsnames

I am trying to migrate to HikariCP for my application connection pool. At the moment, I want to connect to an Oracle database.

Here is the code I am using :

```
        HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
        hc.setUsername(username);
        hc.setPassword(password);
        hc.setDataSourceClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
        hc.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", TNS);
        hc.addDataSourceProperty("portNumber", 1521);
        hc.addDataSourceProperty("driverType", "thin");


        HikariDataSource hds = new HikariDataSource(hc);
        hds.setPoolName("Pool::"+username+"@"+dbName);
```

the TNS variable comes from my config, and reference a setting in the TNSNAMES.ora files present on the server.

```
SERVER_1 =
    (DESCRPTION = 
        (ADDRESS_LIST = 
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = server01.intranet)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECTION_DATA = 
                (SERVICE_NAME = SERVER1)
        )
    )
```

The code fails with the following stacktrace :

```
INFO  HikariPool-1 - Starting...
ERROR HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:443)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:514)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:111)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at com.test.commonlib.config.DbConfigReader.getDataSource(DbConfigReader.java:105)
    at com.test.commonlib.config.DbConfigReader.getDataSource(DbConfigReader.java:31)
    at com.test.module1.Module1.getConnectionModule1(Module1.java:258)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.loadConf(fd.java:583)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.<init>(fd.java:78)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.getInstance(fd.java:84)
    at com.test.module1.Module1.init(Module1.java:78)
    at com.test.module1.scripts.TestPerso.TestPerso.testModule1(TestPerso.java:2009)
    at com.test.module1.scripts.TestPerso.TestPerso.main(TestPerso.java:145)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SERVER_1
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:120)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 25 more
Exception in thread "main" com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:543)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:535)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:111)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at com.test.commonlib.config.DbConfigReader.getDataSource(DbConfigReader.java:105)
    at com.test.commonlib.config.DbConfigReader.getDataSource(DbConfigReader.java:31)
    at com.test.module1.Module1.getConnectionModule1(Module1.java:258)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.loadConf(fd.java:583)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.<init>(fd.java:78)
    at com.test.module1.fileinjector.fd.getInstance(fd.java:84)
    at com.test.module1.Module1.init(Module1.java:78)
    at com.test.module1.scripts.TestPerso.TestPerso.testModule1(TestPerso.java:2009)
    at com.test.module1.scripts.TestPerso.TestPerso.main(TestPerso.java:145)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:666)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:317)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:241)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:443)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:514)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:470)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:506)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:595)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:230)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1452)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:496)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: SERVER_1
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:928)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1323)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1276)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1192)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1126)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:120)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:159)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:428)
    ... 25 more
```

Does anyone got any luck to make it work on Oracle with the TNS NAME ?

Comment: Looks like it wants an actual hostname, instead of the name defining the TNSNAMES entry.  Try setting `TNS` to `server01.hostname` instead of `SERVER_1`.

Comment: Try IP instead of server01.intranet

Comment: Thing is all those informations are already stored in the tnsnames.ora which contains all the information for all my database servers. The point of this file is to avoid writing manually the IP or the dns entry

Comment: For thin driver set sysprop oracle.net.tns_admin -- dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536162/how-to-connect-jdbc-to-tns-oracle and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194750/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-tnsnames-ora

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with JDBC URL instead:

```
dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
dataSource.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server01.intranet:1521/SERVER1")
```

Comment: It does work, even if I simply put 
hc.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVER_1"). Somehow with this way I can use the settings from tnsnames.ora, if not from the Datasource configuration

Comment: So it's a better solution? you accept this suggestion?

Comment: I accept it because I don't have any other solution and it does indeed work. However I wish I could use a datasource without the jdbc url written directly. I opened an issue on github, who knows :)

Comment: can you share the link to the issue?

Comment: See also this solution that my help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536162/how-to-connect-jdbc-to-tns-oracle/28592684

Answer (score 1):

Set the "oracle.net.tns_admin" system property in order to specify a directory location of TNSNAMES.ORA file.

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "C:\\Development\\TNS_ADMIN");
```

If you have TNS_ADMIN system variable set you can do it in following way

```
System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", System.getenv("TNS_ADMIN"));
```