# JDBC remote Oracle connection without listener (TNSNAMES.ora)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to remote Oracle DB using ojdbc6.jar.
JDK 1.8, Oracle 11g.

Listener is not working!:

```
C:\Users\user>lsnrctl services

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on 09-FEB-2018 
20:20:37

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

**Is there a way to connect without using any records in TNSNAMES.ora?**

I've tried a variety of options, but none worked.

**Option #1:**

```
("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//server_address:1521/SERVICE_NAME");
```

(scott = username,tiger = password)

where:

- server_address is the ip, like 169.xx.xx.xxx
- SERVICE_NAME is derived from:

  ```
  SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVICE_NAME') FROM DUAL;
  ```

**Option #2:**

```
("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//SERVER_HOST:1521/SERVICE_NAME")
```

where:
- **SERVER_HOST** is derived from:

```
 SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SERVER_HOST') FROM DUAL;
```

**Option #3:**

```
("jdbc:oracle:thin:scott/tiger@//server_address:1521:SID");
```

where SID derived from:

```
SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'SID') FROM DUAL;
```

**Option #4:**

Same as #1, #2 or #3 but without "//" before the server_address or the SERVER_HOST.

I've tried even more combinations, mixing server_address, SERVER_HOST and SID, but with no avail. I always get the same error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following 
error:
*ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in 
connect descriptor*

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
at 
oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection 
(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at testutil.OracleConnection.main(OracleConnection.java:55)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: Listener refused the connection with 
the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in 
connect descriptor

at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:399)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
... 7 more
```

I think I'm using the right syntax if no TNSNAMES is involved. As far as I researched, if I had the entry in TNSNAMES, the syntax would be as following:

```
("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_address:1521:xe","scott", "tiger");
```

But, unfortunately, I don't have admin rights to \network\admin\sample, so it is not an option in my case.

Comment: Without rights you can't.

Comment: @RomanC Are you saying that I cannot avoid using TNSNAMES.ora in order to connect?

Comment: The order is important.

Comment: In case it's not clear, [`tnsnames.ora`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/netrf/local-naming-parameters-in-tnsnames-ora-file.html) is the local file used by the full Oracle client to associate host/port/service details with labels. Generally the JDBC thin client does not use it (although now that I check, [it appears that it can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14194750/230471)). (Other naming methods are available.) Those details should match one of the services reported by `lsnrctl services` on the database server.

Comment: So for example you might have a tnsnames entry `KITTENS` defined as host=`svalbardprod42`, port=`1521`, service=`kittentracking_app`. Then when you connect as `user/pass@KITTENS`, the Oracle client attempts to contact the listener at `svalbardprod42:1521` and requests a connection to service `kittentracking_app`. (The JDBC thin client works the same way but without the handy configurable labels.) You should be able to confirm each of those items (host exists, listener is running and listening on that port, service is in the list of services.)

Answer (score 1):

Your options are all correct but the listener has to be working properly. The only way to connect if the listener is not functioning properly is on the box using bequeath which the jdbc url would look like this

```
// the url for bequeath connection
String url = "jdbc:oracle:oci8:@";
ods.setURL(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to connect remotely using the JDBC thin driver (JDBC URL starts with `jdbc:oracle:thin`) is through either tcp or tcps both of which require an up and running and registered listener. Once you have the listener running you can try the URLs you have mentioned in your question. I would recommend using a service name instead of SID if you want to use advanced options such as Application Continuity or RAC.