# Connect to oracle from java not using thin in jdbc

Tags: java, oracle

Is there anyway to connect to oracle from java using jdbc driver without specifying any port like the one below?

jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid

admins wants to use someadrees@business.com from tnsnames where it has the host,port and sid.

They don't want to put the port number as one of the variables passed as parameter to the api.

I'm calling the api from a shell script and is passing the host,port and sid.

Comment: Not that I know of.  Why is this an issue?  Should be done using JNDI or similar.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194750/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-tnsnames-ora and this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/urls.htm#BEIDIJCE

Comment: Thanks for all the help. These recommendations worked.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can, the syntax is just `jdbc:oracle:thin@<tnsnames.ora entry>`.

You will have to make sure that the `tnsnames.ora` file is in the TNS_ADMIN directory. You can do that via setting the `oracle.net.tns_admin` system property, either:

`java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=<location to tnsnames.ora>`

Or programmatically, via:

`System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", "<location to tnsnames.ora>");`

If you prefer not to set any other environment variables, the driver will automatically look at `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` next. So in case you have `$ORACLE_HOME` already set, you can just put your `tnsnames.ora` file in there without having to set `$TNS_ADMIN`.

For more information see the [TNSNames Alias Syntax in the Oracle JDBC Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-DEF609D8-7AF9-4D21-93A7-163DA9593F3A).

Comment: Thanks. location of the tnsnames.ora might be a problem for me because im trying to avoid another variable to add to the profile in linux unix env.

Comment: If you already have the `$ORACLE_HOME` variable set the driver will automatically look at `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` as the default location for it

Comment: ah yes.. thanks.  I'll check this one and comeback if successful.

Comment: This solution worked. thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! I have updated the answer with the additional information.