# How to connect apache nifi to oracle db using tnsnames.ora?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, apache-nifi

Is there any way to connect from apache-nifi to ORACLE Database using TNSNAMES.ORA configfile?

I was able to get the connection working through sqlplus

tnsnames.ora is located under /usr/lib/oracle/${release}.${update}/client64/lib/network/admin

`sqlplus user/password@host.abc.com`
The question is about which processor to use, how to load ojdbc.jar to NIFI etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194750/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-tnsnames-ora

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java JDBC - How to connect to Oracle using tnsnames.ora](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194750/java-jdbc-how-to-connect-to-oracle-using-tnsnames-ora)

Comment: How is it duplicate when the question asked was about nifi and the above post was about java jdbc ?